# Internet Explorer Events

Tags: internet-explorer, events, bho

I write the BHO (using VC++ with ATL) for IE where I need to catch the IE events from Address Bar, History, Bookmarks. For example, if the user has typed URL in Address Bar,
then BHO has to show me that URL was entered from Address Bar.

Is it possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something likes this:

```
STDMETHODIMP CBlogUrlSnaggerAddIn2::Exec(
    const GUID *pguidCmdGroup, DWORD nCmdID,
    DWORD nCmdExecOpt, VARIANTARG *pvaIn, VARIANTARG *pvaOut)
{  
    BSTR locationUrl;  
    BSTR locationName;

    m_spWebBrowser->get_LocationURL(&locationUrl);
    m_spWebBrowser->get_LocationName(&locationName);

    MessageBox(NULL, locationUrl, locationName, 0);

    ::SysFreeString(locationUrl);
    ::SysFreeString(locationName);

    return S_OK;
}
```